# Using multiple FileSystemWatchers

Tags: filesystemwatcher

I want to use multiple FileSystemWatchers to watch different text files.

I am successful in creating the watchers and the file change events are being invoked and I can add the changes in the text files to a string and display this on a form.

What I want to know is how I can tell which watcher is causing the event?

Eg. watcher1, watcher2 or watcher3?

I know I can find out the path and file name of the file that has changed but this doesn't really help me.

Comment: OK no answer yet. I think I managed to solve my own problem. I have created an Array with the file paths used for the different watchers. This enables me to link up the watchers with the array and work out which fired which event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you already found your own way to do this, but I recommend you look at the sender parameter within the event that is being fired. This is common for a lot of events. Here is a small example:

```
private static FileSystemWatcher watcherTxt;
private static FileSystemWatcher watcherXml;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String dir = @"C:\temp\";

    watcherTxt = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcherTxt.Path = dir;
    watcherTxt.Filter = "*.txt";
    watcherTxt.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcherTxt.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onCreatedFile);

    watcherXml = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcherXml.Path = dir;
    watcherXml.Filter = "*.xml";
    watcherXml.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcherXml.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onCreatedFile);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void onCreatedFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (watcherTxt == sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text Watcher Detected: " + e.FullPath);
    }

    if (watcherXml == sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("XML Watcher Detected: " + e.FullPath);
    }
}
```